# Using a spec in a urls array option

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add an array of API definitions to my swagger so that I can switch between them in the explorer bar in the swagger-ui. [I have followed the docs to do this](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express#load-swagger-from-url), but I'd like to use a `spec` rather than a `url`. My existing implementation has the following:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

const swaggerDocument = require('../openapi/openapi.json');

const router = express.Router();

router.use('/', swaggerUi.serve);
router.get('/', swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));

module.exports = router;
```

I'd like to do something more like the following:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

const swaggerDocument = require('../openapi/openapi.json');
const swaggerV2Document = require('../openapi/openapiV2.json');

const router = express.Router();

const options = {
    explorer: true,
    swaggerOptions:{
        urls: [
            {
                spec: swaggerDocument,
                name: 'v1'
            },
            {
                spec: swaggerV2Document,
                name: 'v2'
            }
        ]
    }
};

router.use('/', swaggerUi.serve);
router.get('/', swaggerUi.setup(null, options));

module.exports = router;
```

However when I try the above I get an error which I believe comes from the fact the `urls` array expects each object to have a `url` key. I'd have expected the above to follow the same pattern as  everywhere else - if `spec` exists, ignore `url` but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

What is the best way to achieve the above, or is there something I've misunderstood?